# carpet on floor using native camera preview

Tags: android, camera, augmented-reality

i want to display a carpet on floor using native camera preview, how to achieve this? 3d objects like sofa, chair or bed can be done using normal camera. but not able to achieve the same with 2d object like carpet. is there any way or should i have to go with AR framework? if so what is the best framework.

Comment: A real carpet? Do you own one?

Comment: carpet image has to be placed on the floor when u open camera

Comment: A sofa in real life is 3d but an image of a sofa is 2d, just like the carpet

Comment: Yes but when u show sofa image in camera preview, it looks fine as if like real object placed there because its placed vertical. But carpet image has to placed horizontally on the floor...hope u understood my problem

Comment: Your problem is not clear at all. The only way a carpet could be displayed 2D on a floor and look 'real' is if the phone is parallel to the floor, and then you only need x and y axis. But why would you want that? Implement it as 3D, and if by chance the view angle is such that does not require 3D, who cares?

Comment: have u seen any of the furniture apps how they show live camera view.... how that sofa looks in your room, u can c the complete room in live camera placing that sofa at a place. same scenario for me... but my case is carpet, it should be displayed on floor and i should be able to c the complete room. if i place my phone parallel to the floor... complete room would not be seen...hope u understood now